# how does one install gtk for haskell on windows?

Tags: haskell, gtk

has anybody successfully installed gtk for haskell on Windows 7? I've downloaded and unzipped the all-in-one-bundle of GTK+-3 from the website, added the bin directory to my PATH variable, so that pkg-config is found and managed to cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools. The cabal\bin directory is also in my path.

Cabal install gtk however fails.

An extract of the error message is: * Missing C libraries: gobject-2.0, glib-2.0, intl

GS

Comment: I'm not sure but this error means you are missing development libraries.

Comment: In my experience there are issues with cabal and the packages needed, and you need to pass different versions to the cabal-install, and I remember having issues with the tool you need to install it with, and working it out all out is.. ugh.. until someone capable will do something about it, [this is all I have to say](http://i.imgur.com/gPBuAgl.gif).