# Haskell GUI library that actually installs on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell

So far I’ve tried to install gtk2hs and phooey

For the former, (after several failed attempts) I’ve found another question on stackoverflow (without answers but a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460778/how-does-one-install-gtk-for-haskell-on-windows) that indicates that it just doesn’t work), what exactly I tried with the latter, I can’t recall, but it appears to exist no longer.

So is there any GUI-library for Haskell that

- Installs
- Is reasonably easy to use
- Does not lack the most common features; ie there should be (at least)
- - Something to put text at
- - Something to edit text
- - Check(✔)boxes and RatioButtons
- - or something with the same purpose
- - A way to draw arbitrary shapes
- - A way to respond to mouse-click and key-press
- Doesn’t look overly ugly

Comment: The last time I tried to install gtk2hs on Linux, it worked without any problems. But I'm not sure how good it's support is for Windows. This is a good review of the state of the GUI programming in Haskell: http://keera.co.uk/blog/2014/05/23/state-gui-programming-haskell/

Comment: You could try threepenny-gui.  It converts your GUI code into JS and HTML to display in your browser with a webserver backend.

Comment: Radio button is the term you are looking for. Also please provide a link to the stackoverflow question that you found.

Comment: in cas the comment was wrong (or i misread it) here is the other question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460778/how-does-one-install-gtk-for-haskell-on-windows)

Comment: You could try posting a question showing what problems you had with gtk and see if anyone can help with them.

Comment: threepenny-gui installs. however, are there examples (that i can download/copy&paste instead of retype like the github ones (because they lack indentation after c&p)) to verify that it works?

Comment: @Guvante: i had the same proplem as the other person

Comment: threepenny-gui appears to work; at least, i managed to run a first example

Comment: I'm afraid the answer, for the moment, is a plain no. gtk on Windows can install and it's great but an insult to the eyes.

Comment: What about `wxHaskell`? https://wiki.haskell.org/WxHaskell/Windows